# SBT is building external projects in random order

Tags: scala, sbt

I have project with externl projectes, registered in my build file with RootProject class.
In general, I have 4 folders: `app0`, `app1`, `app3` and `app-all` on same level.
There is `project` folder in the `app-all` with following Build.scala file:

```
    import sbt._

object AppBuild extends Build {

  lazy val app2 = RootProject(file("../app0"))
  lazy val app3 = RootProject(file("../app3"))
  lazy val app1 = RootProject(file("../app1"))
  lazy val all = Seq(japp1, app2, app3)
  lazy val root = project.in(file(".")).dependsOn(all.map(ClasspathDependency(_, None)) :_*)
  // lazy val root = project.in(file(".")).aggregate(all.map(sbt.Project.projectToRef) :_*)

}
```

The problem is, that sbt is building those 3 sub-projects in random order.
Once it starts with app1 another time it starts with app3. Same for both aggregate and dependsOn invocation. What are rules of aggregation?
Can I set order somehow?

I expect to set smth like `app1.dependsOn(app3)`  but actually I cannot do it, because it's "project reference" but not real project.

Sbt version 0.13.

-- 
Note: This is test sample with one file, you can create 4 folders by yourself, try to build everything from apps-all and see what is happeninng.

Comment: Out of curiosity what *are* the dependencies? One of the nicities of sbt is that independent projects can be built in parallel.

Comment: basically it's our internal projects that definetly depends on each other. There is a compilation dependency. I can not compile `app1` without publishing `app3`.

Comment: The build definition looks like pre-0.13 style, so I can't say the syntax for sure, but there should be dependsOn relation between sub-projects if the order is important.

Comment: @checat apparently you haven't read post completely.

Comment: @rumoku ok, I've missed that you tried dependOn. But actually, current docs provide an example that looks a little different, and it works. I don't think the `RootProject` is intended for more than single use in a build, and I don't think sbt can build several projects that are "root" projects, but I may be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

In latest sbt 0.13 it's done like this.

`` lazy val `root` = (project in file(".")).
    aggregate(`sub-a`, `sub-b`)
lazy val `sub-a` = (project in file("a"))
lazy val `sub-b` = (project in file("b")).
  dependsOn(`sub-a`) ``

According to docs, http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Multi-Project.html#Classpath+dependencies

> This also creates an ordering between the projects when compiling them